# Matching Colormap and Colorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm running the following code

```
%    x_start y_start x_end y_end concentration
A = [0         0      1      1     10
     0         1      3      3     0.6
     3         1      6      2     1.2];

cmap = jet(256);
con_min = 0;
con_max = 10;
ind_c = round((size(cmap,1)-1)*A(:,5)/(con_max-con_min))+1
figure;
set(gca,'ColorOrder',cmap(ind_c,:),'NextPlot','replacechildren');
plot([A(:,1) A(:,3)]',[A(:,2) A(:,4)]');
colorbar
```

However, my colorbar is not matching up with my colormap; it's using the default colorbar, and I'm running a custom colormap. How can I make it so that my colorbar shows the right values for my colormap?

Comment: can you not use `colormap(cmap)` instead of `set(gca,'ColorOrder',cmap(ind_c,:),'NextPlot','replacechildren');`?

Comment: @Dan Yep, that was it!